# How did this matrix get created from the inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, affine-geometry

I am new to matrices and to systems of inequalities. When I look at a matrix it's difficult to tell where the $1's$, $0's$ and $-1's$ come from. I know they somehow come from the inequality itself, but for some reason I'm not seeing *how*.

My questions are:

1. How these **inequalities** become (get plugged into) these **matrices** ([source](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/~achauhan/Teaching/B629/2010-Fall/StudentPresns/PolyhedralModelOverview.pdf)):
   $$
   1 \leq i \leq n : 
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1 & 0\\
     -1 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     i\\
     j
   \end{pmatrix}
   +
   \begin{pmatrix}
     -1\\
     n
   \end{pmatrix}
   \geq 0
   $$
   $$
   1 \leq j \leq n : 
   \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 1\\
     0 & -1
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix}
     i\\
     j
   \end{pmatrix}
   +
   \begin{pmatrix}
     -1\\
     n
   \end{pmatrix}
   \geq 0
   $$
2. Specifically, how $1 \leq i \leq n$ becomes \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
3. And how $1 \leq i \leq n$ becomes \begin{pmatrix}-1\\n\end{pmatrix}

---

Now I'll describe the problem I'm having in more detail if that's helpful.

*(I assume this equation is from [$\textbf{A}\vec{x} + \vec{b} \geq 0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Representation)).*

Take for example these two parts:

$$
(a):1 \leq i \leq n\ \ \ \  
(b):\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I know (a) can be rewritten into a set of two inequalities (though I'm not even sure I'm doing that right):

\begin{align}
0 &\leq -1 + i\\
0 &\leq -i + n
\end{align}

So then in my attempt to figure out how the inequality goes into the matrix, I do this:

\begin{align}
0 &\leq -1 + i \mapsto -1, 1\\
0 &\leq -i + n \mapsto -1, 1
\end{align}

since $\mathbf{-1} + i$ is like $(\mathbf{-1} + (\mathbf{1} \times i))$ and $\mathbf{-}i + n$ is like $((\mathbf{-1} \times i) + (\mathbf{1} \times n))$. But that would lead to a matrix like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  -1 & 1\\
  -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

when it should be

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So I'm confused how that matrix (b) gets created from the inequality (a). The same goes for the second matrix in the first diagram.

Also, I am not sure where this comes from either:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  -1\\
  n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The full set of inequalities/matrices (if it's helpful) is below. I'm basically just trying to understand how they got those matrix equations from the inequalities in the diagram:

[image]

[image]

They got the inequalities out of the for loop if that helps.

Another example is the following diagram. Even though they have the *colors* showing how they mapped the values, I still don't see how they did it (went from inequality $\to$ matrix).

[image]

I would simply like to know how to do it for one of these inequality/matrices pairs, so I can apply it to all of them. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is basically breaking $1\leq i\leq n$ into two parts $1\leq i$ and $i\leq n$.

You then make both of them as nonnegativity conditions $i-1\geq 0$ and $-i+n\geq0$ so they are now

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}i + \begin{bmatrix}-1\\n\end{bmatrix} \geq 0
$$
Since nothing depends on $j$ for these inequalities we can add the dummy constraint $0j\geq 0$ and everything stays the same

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}-1\\n\end{bmatrix} \geq 0
$$

You can do the same for $j$.